# ATMEGA328P-AU with USB capabilities

Tags: microcontroller, usb, usb-device, atmega328p, hid

I would like to use an [ATMEGA328P-AU](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809101618_Microchip-Tech-ATMEGA328P-AU_C14877.pdf) microcontroller with USB capabilities (to program it and turn it into a USB Human Interface Device). So, I am thinking of using a [CP2102-GMR](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1811081920_SILICON-LABS-CP2102-GMR_C6568.pdf) to do that. Is it a good idea? How can I connect them?

Comment: While you *could* do that, did you have a look into *V-USB*? That's a pure software solution for AVR controllers that makes them a low-speed USB device. For HIDs, it's usually sufficient. I did a custom keyboard emulator with that.

Comment: @Janka I would like to use a 100% hardware solution

Comment: Then you can't use the CP2102-GMR as it does not present itself to the host computer as a HID. It's handled as a COM port on host side.

Comment: @Janka, what do you recommend me? I am a newbie and I want to order the assembly from jlcpcb (basic parts)

Comment: I recommend you to take a deeper look into V-USB. It's just a software you had to put on the AVR along with your software. They have different profiles and a lot of example projects on their site. You don't need anything special but the AVR. The host sees the sort of USB device you want it to see. The only limitation is that the resulting device is low-speed USB.

Answer (score 4):

It is not a good idea. You can't implement a HID with CP2102 because it is a USB serial comms interface.

Use virtual USB with that AVR, or a different AVR with USB interface, or use some other MCU with USB interface.

Comment: I can not use virtual USB because it should be work in multiple OS with no additional software. So, could you recommend me another MCU? (very easy to weld)

Comment: @Amparo You are mistaken and that is not how it works. If the AVR has no hardware USB, you can implement USB in software. The PC does not care how AVR physically implements USB, as long as it logically implements a standard HID device.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but I need use a hardware solution because I need it works on multiple OS with no software installed

Comment: @Amparo No you don't seem to understand, if you keep saying you need a hardware USB solution. A software USB implementation running on AVR will show up as standard HID device and will work on multiple OSes without drivers. So no, you don't need an hardware USB on AVR for that.